# Having Content beeing stacked from the left and a button on the right in wpf .net 4.8

Tags: .net, wpf, layout, orientation

### Goal:

I am on a small project for my own audio library.
The Idea is to have a list of audio files with some information displayed. It can be compared to the file explorer in list view mode:
[image]

So far, this is quite easy to archieve with a Grid.

Additionally, I would like to have a play/pause button displayed to the full right of the element

### Issue:

Right now, I am using a Stack Panel. Therefore the play button sticks to the right of the grid, possibly even going out of screen when too many elements are displayed:
[image]

the code I am currently using is the following:

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="title" Content="Title" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
        <Label x:Name="duration" Content="Duration" Grid.Column="1"></Label>
    </Grid>
    <Button x:Name="PlayPause_Button" Content=">" MinWidth="40" ></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

### Goal:

I would like to have the Button stick to the right of the element. Possibly in front of the Grid in case the user selects more metadata to display than fits on the element.
[image]

Comment: There is DockPanel. You would not even need the inner Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use StackPanel only for Labels:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label x:Name="title" Content="Title" />
        <Label x:Name="duration" Content="Duration" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Button x:Name="PlayPause_Button" Content=">" MinWidth="40" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I guess I'll need another nested grid instead of the stackpanel, because consistent cell widths throughout instances are of concern.
Anyways, this is well adaptable for my issue. Thank you for the fast and great solution. I somehow couldn't wrap my head around.

Comment: "It can be compared to the file explorer in list view mode" - maybe you should use DataGrid or ListView. They align headers with content cells.